# Error when presenting dates I stored in sqlite3 db in iphone development

Tags: iphone, objective-c, date, sqlite

I get this error when trying to to represent the stored dates
my question is what is this error ?

### error:

```
2011-11-13 10:06:36.001 Holiday[217:207] -[NSNull cc_componentsForMonthDayAndYear]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x259ed68
2011-11-13 10:06:36.039 Holiday[217:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull cc_componentsForMonthDayAndYear]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x259ed68'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x02534b99 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0268440e objc_exception_throw + 47
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x025366ab -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x024a62b6 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x024a5e72 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   Holiday                             0x00008c7e +[KalDate dateFromNSDate:] + 44
    6   Holiday                             0x0000fc36 -[KalViewController loadedDataSource:] + 265
    7   Holiday                             0x000081d4 -[HolidaySqliteDataSource loadHolidaysFrom:to:delegate:] + 873
    8   Holiday                             0x00008560 -[HolidaySqliteDataSource presentingDatesFrom:to:delegate:] + 97
    9   Holiday                             0x0000f848 -[KalViewController reloadData] + 162
    10  Holiday                             0x0000fe16 -[KalViewController showAndSelectDate:] + 276
    11  Holiday                             0x000065ab -[HolidayAppDelegate showAndSelectToday] + 90
    12  UIKit                               0x002e27f8 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    13  UIKit                               0x004ee68b -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 156
    14  UIKit                               0x002e27f8 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    15  UIKit                               0x0036dde0 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    16  UIKit                               0x00370262 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
    17  UIKit                               0x0036ee0f -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
    18  UIKit                               0x003063d0 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
    19  UIKit                               0x002e7cb4 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
    20  UIKit                               0x002ec9bf _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7672
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x02d90822 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x02515ff4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x02476807 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x02473a93 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x02473350 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x02473271 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    27  GraphicsServices                    0x02d8f00c GSEventRunModal + 217
    28  GraphicsServices                    0x02d8f0d1 GSEventRun + 115
    29  UIKit                               0x002f0af2 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    30  Holiday                             0x00001fd4 main + 102
    31  Holiday                             0x00001f65 start + 53
    32  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

### presenting function code :

```
- (void)loadHolidaysFrom:(NSDate *)fromDate to:(NSDate *)toDate delegate:(id<KalDataSourceCallbacks>)delegate
{
  NSLog(@"Fetching holidays from the database between %@ and %@...", fromDate, toDate);
    sqlite3 *db;
  NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

    if(sqlite3_open([[self databasePath] UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK) {
        const char *sql = "select name, country, date_of_event from holidays where date_of_event between ? and ?";
        sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
      [fmt setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
      sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [[fmt stringFromDate:fromDate] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
      sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [[fmt stringFromDate:toDate] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
      [fmt setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
            while(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSString *name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0)];
                NSString *country = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1)];
        NSString *dateAsText = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2)];
        [holidays addObject:[Holiday holidayNamed:name country:country date:[fmt dateFromString:dateAsText]]];
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    }
    sqlite3_close(db);
  [delegate loadedDataSource:self];
}
```

### insert function, which insert dates

```
-(NSNumber*) insertDate: (NSDate*) d
{
    NSLog(@"inserting date into database");
    sqlite3 *db;
    NSNumber *re = [NSNumber numberWithInt:-1];
    NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
    if(sqlite3_open([[self databasePath]UTF8String],&db)==SQLITE_OK){
        const char *sql = "insert into holidays(name, country, date_of_event) values(?,?,?)";
        sqlite3_stmt *addStmt;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,sql,-1,&addStmt,NULL)==SQLITE_OK){
            [fmt setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
            NSString *country = @"country test";
            NSString *name =@"name test";
            sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt,1,[name UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_STATIC);
            sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt,2,[country UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_STATIC);
            sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt,3,[[fmt stringFromDate:d]UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_STATIC);
        }
        if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt)){
            NSAssert1(0,@"Error in inserting into database %s",sqlite3_errmsg(db));
        }else {
            re = [NSNumber numberWithInt: sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(db)];
            sqlite3_finalize(addStmt);
            sqlite3_close(db);
        }
    }
    return re;
}
```

Comment: Any reason you didn't include dateFromNSDate, where the error actually occurred?

Comment: @DanielRHicks, where exactly do you mean I have to use it ?

Comment: I mean show us the source for it, since that's where the error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error message. My solution required that I "chop" the time off of my date string. Another words truncate "2013-06-03 13:42:34 +0000" to "2013-06-03". The Kal function called by holiday wanted only the date.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, Kal takes NSDate as input in its internal methods. So make sure your object has NSDate and not NSString!